# Can't loop through an ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy object on controller's destroy action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to access individual items in an ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy by looping through it in a destroy action.

To best explain my problem, I'll share some code.

Here is how my controller code looks like:

```
def destroy
  @role.destroy
  // Simple puts to show what data is here
  puts @role # => <Role:0x000055850068acb0>
  puts @role.rules.inspect # => <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
  @role.rules.map do | rule |
    puts rule # => doesn't output anything
    SomeClass.new(@role.rules, rule.field, ...).call_function()
  end
end
```

Here is how I set a role:

```
def set_role
  @role = current_company.roles.find_by_id!(params[:id])
end
```

The problem is that looping through the role rules, i.e `@role.rules.map` does not work, I am guessing this is because the children of the roles are already deleted.

The association has a `dependent: :destroy` clause to it.

As we can see, the `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []` object is empty since all of the role's children are deleted on delete of the role.

How do I ensure that I capture the role and it's dependent associations even after a destroy action has been deleted? I hope this makes sense. I have tried to abstract it and as simple as possible. Sorry if the code does not make sense, I am explaining it without exposing a lot of code. Thanks

**EDIT**

I realize there is a problem with the question.

There is another table in play, `Bundle`. A rule `belongs_to` a `bundle` and a `bundle` has_many rules. Therefore, by deleting a role, I want to ensure that I am able to send a message that a bundle has been updated with the removal of rules.

**NB** `SomeClass` is a library class, inside `/lib`, I am using to send events. This basically means I am sending out a message with the details of the `Bundle`. This message tells us that when a role was deleted, the rules were deleted and this is the `bundle` without the following rules.

Comment: Why you use `@rule` inside the loop. It is not declared anywhere. The operator of loop seems to be  `rule` instead

Comment: Yes, My bad. Editing the question

Comment: you can run the loop before deletion right?trying to understand why you want the reverse order

Comment: Yes, I can loop through before, but I want to capture the change in the rules. When a delete occurs, I would want to capture the effect it has on the rule and use that data somewhere. I can not capture this before the delete occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my understanding you can use callback in your models

open your role model app/models/role.rb

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  # callback
    before_destroy :check_rules


  # here is the callback method that will run automatically before destroy
  def check_rules
    puts self # in model your @role is equal to self
    self.rules.map do |rule|
      puts rule
      # other action
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think `SomeClass` will have access to `@role`, but yes I get the idea, let me try it out.

Comment: yes you correct, I don't know your other class is it service or other model, but I believe you get the idea for before_destroy

Comment: @kevinsamoei Maybe we would have a better idea of your intentions if we knew exactly what the `SomeClass` initializer does with `@role`. If you're just storing `@role` as an instance variable, I don't think that's the right approach - you'd want to capture the relevant `@role` attribute data and store that instead. Same for the child `Rule`s.

Comment: @taylorthurlow I have edited the question with more details. I hope it is clear, if not let me know.

Comment: @kevinsamoei Ok, things are a little clearer. You said in the other answer that you wanted to "ensure that the effect of deleting a role has on rules and capture that". What exactly is the effect of deleting a role on rules? Roles have many child rules, and the rules get deleted when the role does.

Comment: @taylorthurlow You are right, it does not make sense, I think by abstracting the problem I messed up. Let me update it once again with more details.

Comment: @kevinsamoei I read your update. I'm still trying to figure out why it wouldn't work to use a `before_destroy` callback. In the callback you have access to the `@role` (as `self`). There should be no issues passing `self` into the `SomeClass::new`.

Comment: @taylorthurlow Can I set a variable in the model `before_destroy` callback? This is because the class can not be instantiated in the model since it also requires the `current_user`

Comment: @kevinsamoei I see what you mean. Perhaps [a workaround like this](http://geekhmer.github.io/blog/2016/01/27/how-to-make-session-data-available-to-models-in-ruby-on-rails/) might be helpful?

Comment: @kevinsamoei Sweet! Glad I could help. Make sure to vote up any comments/answers that helped you to your solution, as well as accepting the answer that you feel best answers your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of your code seems lost in your effort to abstract the problem (which is fine, simple code is good). Is your goal to use attribute data from the `rules` in the instantiation of new `SomeClass`es? In other words, you want to delete the records (both the `Role` and the `Rule`s) but use the attributes from the deleted `Rule`s to create some new `SomeClass` instances.

It seems to me like before calling `@role.destroy` you could store the result of `@role.rules.map(&:dup)` in a variable. This will duplicate the roles, but won't assign them new ids (or store them in the database).

Alternatively, is there anything wrong with just instantiating the `SomeClass`es before calling `@role.destroy`? Or do you need to make sure the `@role` gets destroyed before creating the `SomeClass`es?

Comment: When I instantiate the class before calling `destroy`, I will be using the wrong data and that won't be good. Also, saving the duplicate has the same effect as looping before `destroy` or instantiating the class before `destroy`. I will be using the wrong data.

Comment: I want to ensure that the effect of deleting a role has on rules and capture that.

Comment: Gotcha. I think in this case, that the `before_destroy` callback mentioned in the other answer is probably the way to go.